# Difference in standard deviation when creating normal standard

Tags: normal-distribution

I havent quite understood when to use
$$\frac{X -μ}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

and when to use
$$\frac{X -μ}{\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}}}$$

and finally
$$\frac{X -μ}{σ}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information is missing from the question. I have answered based on the what I could guess. Note that $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ is the standard deviation of $\bar{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}$. And $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$ is an estimate of the standard deviation of $\bar{X}$ when $\sigma$ is unknown.

**So if your random variable (RV) $X$ is the average of $n$ i.i.d. RVs**, use $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ when you know $\sigma$, otherwise use the estimate of $\sigma$, that is, $s$.

If you RV $X$ is such that it has standard deviation $\sigma$, use $\sigma$.